# Delete UIImageView which is created programmatically

Tags: ios, button

I am new to iOS development and I wanted help with this:

I want to delete an image that was created automatically with a click of a button...
if the button is clicked twice 2 images will be created..
so i just want to delete one... the one which i want...

How do I do that??

I already have code to move around both the images with pan gesture recognizer.
I just can't figure it out. How to delete the image which I want?

I have an idea though but, I do not know how to implement it.

This is what I want:

I want to select the image and then there will be a button called delete, when I click the delete button the selected image gets deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assign tags to your images and the call removeFromSuperView on the relevant imageView when you wanna delete.